# Laravel image path stored as .tmp name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have a question about upload image. The image uploaded in my path but name of db is wrong like that: http://prntscr.com/10p5ths

My Controller code:

```
public function store(ActivityCreateRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image_url')) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($request->file('image_url') as $image_url) {
            $fileName = Str::slug($request->title). time(). $i .'.'.$image_url->extension();
            $fileNameWithUpload = 'uploads/activities/'.$fileName;
            $image_url->move(public_path('uploads/activities'),$fileName);
            $request->merge([
                'image_url' => $fileNameWithUpload
            ]);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if ($request->hasFile('video_url')) {
        $i = 10;
        foreach ($request->file('video_url') as $video_url) {
            $fileName = Str::slug($request->title). time(). $i .'.'.$video_url->extension();
            $fileNameWithUpload = 'uploads/activities/'.$fileName;
            $video_url->move('uploads/activities/',$fileName);
            $request->merge([
                'video_url' => $fileNameWithUpload
            ]);
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $activity =  new Activity;
    $activity->title = $request->title;
    $activity->company_name = $request->company_name;
    $activity->price = $request->price;
    $activity->description = $request->description;
    $activity->save();

    if ($activity->save() === true) {

        $data = [];

        foreach ($request->image_url as $key => $value) {
            $data[] = [
                'activity_id' => $activity->id,
                'image' => $value,
                'video' => $request->video_url[$key] ?? null,
                'created_at' => now()
            ];
        }

        if (! empty($data)) {
            ActivityAsset::insert($data);
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('activities.index');

}
```

Files is uploaded in public folder with correct name. But not same as db name. What can i do?

Comment: What does `$data` have in it (assuming nothing) in your saving code?

Comment: @hppycoder as you see is a array and in foreach i am uploaded multiple file (video and image)

Comment: You need to change `'image' => $value,` to `'image' => Str::slug($key) . $value->extension(),` (but your image name will be different, cause you use 2 foreach loop. you need 1 foreach)

Comment: @Vedat I see what you want it to do but you should share what it actually does. As in does your `$data` contain everything you think it does. We can't see that without recreating your environment. The next thing we'll ask for then is for you to do a `var_dump($request->image_url)` next if `$data` is empty

Comment: @Droid its not working :/ I got error.

Comment: @hppycoder var_dump result: http://prntscr.com/10p6rpc

Comment: Notice then how `$request->image_url` appears to be an array of instances of `UploadedFile` which I believe you wanted it to be an array of the filenames?

Answer (score 1):

Using the class above I've separated out the saving of the assets away from that of the main controller method `store`

Working through the comments I've also set `image` on the `ActivityAsset` to a value when uploading an image. This will allow you to query your data and determine if you should show a video or show an image. Either a media player for a video or a `<img>` tag for the presentation.

```php
<?php

class YourController
{
    public function store(ActivityCreateRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('image_url')) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($request->file('image_url') as $image_url) {
                $fileName = Str::slug($request->title) . time() . $i . '.' . $image_url->extension();
                $fileNameWithUpload = 'uploads/activities/' . $fileName;
                $image_url->move(public_path('uploads/activities'), $fileName);
                $this->storeContent($request, $fileNameWithUpload, 'image');
                $i++;
            }
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('video_url')) {
            $i = 10;
            foreach ($request->file('video_url') as $video_url) {
                $fileName = Str::slug($request->title) . time() . $i . '.' . $video_url->extension();
                $fileNameWithUpload = 'uploads/activities/' . $fileName;
                $video_url->move('uploads/activities/', $fileName);
                $this->storeContent($request, $fileNameWithUpload, 'video');
                $i++;
            }
        }

        return redirect()->route('activities.index');
    }

    /**
     * @param $request
     * @param $fileName
     * @param $type
     * @return bool
     */
    private function storeContent($request, $fileName, $type)
    {
        $activity = new Activity;
        $activity->title = $request->title;
        $activity->company_name = $request->company_name;
        $activity->price = $request->price;
        $activity->description = $request->description;
        $activity->save();

        if ($activity->save() === true) {
            return ActivityAsset::insert([
                'activity_id' => $activity->id,
                'image' => ($type == 'image' ? $fileName : null),
                'video' => ($type == 'video' ? $fileName : null),
                'created_at' => now()
            ]);
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've added the `class YourController` feel free to remove I just wanted it to display correctly on here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i got error your second code. : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

The ss: http://prntscr.com/10p73ja

Comment: Please edit your original question and put the full controller if possible. You gave us snippets which has other contexts above it.

Comment: Perfect, so when a video is uploaded should the `image` field be `null`?

Comment: How do you know it's a video or if it's an image? I thought `image` would be null if video and vice versa

Comment: In my blade, <input type="file" class="custom-file-input"  name="video_url[]" multiple accept="video/mp4"> and my validation mime types